# Реакт делает ре-рендер кастомных компонентов при изменении state?

Tags: reactjs

По примеру:

```
<Select age={age}>
 <Input name={name}/>
</Select>
```

`Input` будет ререндериться, если `name` не изменится, а `age` изменится?

Comment: Думаю да, но вы можете дополнительно это проверить с использованием расширения React DevTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, в React при изменении state, компоненты, которые используют этот state, будут перерендерены. Если в вашем примере состояние age изменится, то компонент Select и его дочерние элементы, включая Input, будут перерендерены. Если состояние name изменится, то только компонент Input будет перерендерен.